# Eigenvalues of $(2n+1) \times (2n+1)$ matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What are the eigenvalues of a symmetric $(2n+1) \times (2n+1)$ matrix $A$, where

$$A= \left( \begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 0 & 3 & 3 &... &3 &1 &1 &...&1\\
3 & 0 & 3 &... &3 &1 &1 &...&1\\
.&.&.&...&.&.& &...&\\
3 & 3 & 3 &... &0 &1 &1 &...&1\\
1 &1 &1&... &1 &0 &1 & ...&1\\
1 &1 &1&... &1 &1 &0 & ...&1\\
.&.&.&...&.&.&...&\\
1 &1 &1&... &1 &1&1 & ...&0
\end{array}\right)$$

First block is of size $(n+1) \times (n+1)$
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 3 & 3 &... &3 \\
3 & 0 & 3 &... &3\\
.&.&.&...&.\\
3 & 3 & 3 &... &0 
\end{array}\right)$$

, second block is of size $(n+1)\times n$
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 &... &1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 &... &1\\
.&.&.&...&.\\
1 &1 & 1 &... &1 
\end{array}\right)$$,
 third block is of size $n \times (n+1)$ 
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 &... &1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 &... &1\\
.&.&.&...&.\\
1 &1 & 1 &... &1 
\end{array}\right)$$
and fourth block is of size $n \times n$ $$\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 1 & 1 &... &1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 &... &1\\
.&.&.&...&.\\
1 &1 & 1 &... &0 
\end{array}\right)$$.

Comment: Sorry I can't quite tell what's going on here. Can you make explicit what your blocks are?

Comment: Well, it's pretty clear that $-3$ is an eigenvalue of high multiplicity, as is $-1$, and the sum of the eigenvalues is zero --- that should get you started.