# Eigenvalues of symmetric (2n+1)×(2n+1) matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The two distinct eigenvalues of the following matrix are $-3$ (with multiplicity n) and $-1$ (with multiplicity $n-1$). What are the remaining two distinct eigenvalues of a symmetric $(2n+1) \times (2n+1)$ matrix $A$, where

$$A= \left( \begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 0 & 3 & 3 &... &3 &1 &1 &...&1\\
3 & 0 & 3 &... &3 &1 &1 &...&1\\
.&.&.&...&.&.& &...&\\
3 & 3 & 3 &... &0 &1 &1 &...&1\\
1 &1 &1&... &1 &0 &1 & ...&1\\
1 &1 &1&... &1 &1 &0 & ...&1\\
.&.&.&...&.&.&...&\\
1 &1 &1&... &1 &1&1 & ...&0
\end{array}\right)$$

First block is of size $(n+1) \times (n+1)$
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 3 & 3 &... &3 \\
3 & 0 & 3 &... &3\\
.&.&.&...&.\\
3 & 3 & 3 &... &0 
\end{array}\right)$$

, second block is of size $(n+1)\times n$
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 &... &1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 &... &1\\
.&.&.&...&.\\
1 &1 & 1 &... &1 
\end{array}\right)$$,
 third block is of size $n \times (n+1)$ 
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 &... &1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 &... &1\\
.&.&.&...&.\\
1 &1 & 1 &... &1 
\end{array}\right)$$
and fourth block is of size $n \times n$ $$\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 1 & 1 &... &1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 &... &1\\
.&.&.&...&.\\
1 &1 & 1 &... &0 
\end{array}\right)$$.

Comment: You asked the same question a few days ago, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664428/eigenvalues-of-2n1-times-2n1-matrix --- better to make some edit in the old question than to post a second copy. Also, you did not engage with the comment I left on the earlier post.

Comment: The sum of the eigenvalues of $A$ is the trace of $A$ and the product of the eigenvalues is the determinant of $A$. You have two unknowns and two equations, so it might be solvable. The trace is easy to find, but I'm not sure if the determinant is that easy.

Comment: Thank you. The determinant is $2n(n-2)$ and the trace is $0$. So the remaining two distinct eigenvalues are $\frac{-(4n-1)+\sqrt{(8n^2+8n+1)}}{2}$ and $\frac{-(4n-1)-\sqrt{(8n^2+8n+1)}}{2}$.